# flex tree gets chopped even after using scroll bar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, custom-controls, horizontal-scrolling, treeviewitem

when i use the following tree renderer class the the informtions in the tree gets chopped. Is there any solution to fix this bug. please help me.
The PLTree class is as follows:

```
import flash.events.Event;
    import mx.events.ScrollEvent;
    import mx.controls.Tree;
    import mx.core.ScrollPolicy;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.events.TreeEvent;

    public class PLTree extends Tree
    {
        private var _lastWidth:Number = 0;
        private var _lastHeight:Number = 0;
        public function PLTree() {
            super();
            horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.AUTO;
        }       
       override public function get maxHorizontalScrollPosition():Number
       {
            return mx_internal::_maxHorizontalScrollPosition;
       }     
       override public function set maxHorizontalScrollPosition(value:Number):void
       {
            mx_internal::_maxHorizontalScrollPosition = value;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("maxHorizontalScrollPositionChanged"));      
            scrollAreaChanged = true;
            invalidateDisplayList();
       }      
       override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
       {
            var diffWidth:Number = measureWidthOfItems(0,0) - (unscaledWidth - viewMetrics.left - viewMetrics.right);

            if (diffWidth <= 0) {
                maxHorizontalScrollPosition = 0;
                horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            } else {
                maxHorizontalScrollPosition = diffWidth;
                horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON;
            }
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
       }
    override protected function scrollHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        if (mx_internal::isOpening)
            return;

        // TextField.scroll bubbles so you might see it here
        if (event is ScrollEvent){

            super.scrollHandler(event);
            invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    }   
}
```

i am attaching the image file of how it looks when executed.
[image]

When surfing using google i found a suggesion to fix this bug is it the right way ?
(

```
Issue: Text getting chopped of at end.
Fix: change
maxHorizontalScrollPosition = diffWidth;
to
maxHorizontalScrollPosition = diffWidth + 10;
or what ever correction factor you need.
```

)

Kindly help me .Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please feel free to ask for additional information.

Comment: When i move the horizontal scroll bar of the tree the variables in the tree view show up completely. but when i move the vertical scroll bar the newly viewed varables get chopped.

Comment: Why no one is reponding to my post ? does it has any problem, Kindly let me know the problem..

Comment: It's just not an easy question. That's what you get when a site rewards fast and easy answers more than elaborate, complex ones. Anyway: you might want to describe what is the behavior of the Tree you want to achieve. There may be an easier solution.

Comment: when i use the scroll bar to scroll everything goes fine, but when i use mouse-wheel to scroll the tree get chopped. i don't want my tree to get chopped. kindly help me. also check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103948/flex-mouse-scroll-bar-issue) to view the preview of bug

Comment: wen i use the scroll bar everythin works fine but when i use the mouseWheel scroll the tree gets cutoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to the scroll handler in the above mentioned program.  Use a mouse wheel scroll handler to handle that event as follows:

```
override protected function mouseWheelHandler(eventMouse:MouseEvent):void
     {      if (mx_internal::isOpening)
            return;

        if (eventMouse is MouseEvent){          
            super.mouseWheelHandler(eventMouse);
            invalidateDisplayList();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your picture, I'd suspect the issue has nothing to do with the specific tree, and is only slightly related to the renderer.  Instead, I think that when the container holding the Tree is created, it doesn't have a size, and when the Tree sizes its renderers, it gives them the wrong size.  Since List-based controls don't set the actual width on renderers, choosing to set explicitWidth instead, the renderers aren't triggered into changing their size.

Check out http://www.developria.com/2009/12/handling-delayed-instantiation-1.html for more explicit details and fixes.