# how to set truncateToFit option to true in the Tree in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tree, itemrenderer, custom-component

I am trying to customise the truncateToFit option in my Custom Tree. In order to do that i have to render a LABEL into my tree as the tree is not having the TruncateToFit property. I am begineer to flex, and i surfed a lot to see how they have rendered label inside a tree but i dint find any solution.

Is my prediction right ? If it is right then how to render a label inside a tree component ?

```
<ns1:PLTree  verticalAlign="top" rendererIsEditor="true" columnWidth="150" height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0" borderThickness="0" dragEnabled="false" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" dataProvider="{dBTree}"  iconFunction="getTreeIcon" labelField="label" iconField="icon" showRoot="false"  allowMultipleSelection="true" id="treTree" doubleClickEnabled="true" >
<ns1:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:Label truncateToFit="true" /> 
    </mx:Component>
</ns1:itemRenderer>
</ns1:PLTree>
```

but if i do like this the tree's property get override and everything is displayed as text. output is follows
[image]

kindly help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I tried to use truncateToFit in the tree renderer, but it is passing an error.. can any one show a example code of how to do it please

Comment: refer to the following link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088097/flex-tree-gets-chopped-even-after-using-scroll-bar/7267149#7267149

Comment: Why not use an uneditable text area rather than a label.The textarea will take care of wrapping text to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an item renderer for that tree
That item renderer would extend treeitemrenderer component.
It should work fine

```
 <mx:Tree id="treeid"                                                                     
    width="100%" height="100%"  
    labelField="@label"                 
    itemRenderer="your renderer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you also need to set maxlines or maxDisplayedLines to 1 when using to fit